# Can you make separate schedules for workflows on staging versus prod?

Tags: flyte

I would like to have certain workflows run on a different schedule in staging and in production (ex: one workflow run multiple times a day in staging and only once a day in production). Doing so would help with getting quicker feedback on the runs and also save on compute costs. How can I do this with flytekit? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this as it goes against main integration/deployment strategy championed by Flyte.

Flyte entities, comprising tasks, workflow, and launch plans, are designed to be iterated under in a user's `development` domain.  After iterating, users are expected to deploy that version to the `staging` domain and then to `production`.  The more difference there are between those domains, the more confusion there will be down the road we suspect.

That said, it is possible to do this because the registration step allows the user to specify a different configuration file.  One of the entries in the configuration file is [this](https://github.com/lyft/flytekit/blob/3d6437bece660c872085f08d41a1a3a27e7ffd8b/flytekit/configuration/sdk.py#L5) `workflow_packages` construct.  This enables the user basically to look at different folders when registering in staging vs. production for instance.

In order to get a launch plan to only exist in one domain, you'll need to put it in a new folder/module that is inaccessible from any of the extant workflow packages, and then put the other one in yet another.

In the staging file,

```
[sdk]
workflow_packages=app.workflows,staging_lps
```

In the production file,

```
[sdk]
workflow_packages=app.workflows,production_lps
```